# How to make all lines in a text file a variable?

Tags: python

I am new to coding and I was wondering if you could import a txt file and change all of those lines into variables that are all random numbers? So pretty much I just want to import a txt file with 80 lines, and change all of those lines into random numbers that are all different.

Sorry If this is a bad explanation I'll try to answer questions

Edit: I don't necessarily have a version of code for this, Sorry. But pretty much I want to load all lines in a txt file and assign them all a random number. Then pretty much in the end I want all the line to be assigned a different number. e.g. Albania - 19, Andorra - 15 and repeat, then all of these numbers need to be different.

Comment: Better to provide code/pseudocode and a small example of desired result. But in all honesty, why the need to turn them into variables? You can always read them all into a list (for example, via `.readlines()` or somesuch) and access via `listofrands[0]`, `listofrands[1]`, etc. Is there a reason why this is not effective for you?

Comment: What does assigning a (random) number to a line mean?

Comment: I just want to import the lines, then someone assign each line a random number, like Albania = random.randint(1, 189) but i want this to be much compacter rather than listing out every line and assigning them 1 by 1

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense. Lines are (probably) strings, so assigning a number to them would change them into integers. I think you need to learn about programming and Python a little better…

Comment: hust show a text file with three lines and then show the text file after the program modified it.

Comment: So would that fulfil your requirement.

take a file. count how many lines it contains, delete the file, create a new file with the same name, that contains a different number (between 1 and the max line number??) in each lines and has the same amount if lines than the initial file???

Comment: What it sounds like you want is a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the lines, and the values are random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a dictionary whose keys are the lines and values are random numbers.

You can do it by reading the lines into a list, shuffling the list randomly, then pairing them up in the dictionary with sequential numbers.

```
import random

with open("filename.txt") as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f]
random.shuffle(names)
d = { name:n for n, name in enumerate(names) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read all the lines into an array using file.readlines() and then another array to store the random indices. For example:

```
import random
lines = file.readlines()
indices = [random.randint(0, len(lines)-1) for i in range(len(lines)]
```

To access the element with random number 1, therefore, you could do this:

```
lines[indices[1]]
```